# Select all text right of the cursor

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a shortcut to do `Ctrl + Shift + →`. But instead of selecting a single word you select the entire page right of the cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly in Word, the keyboard combination of `Ctrl + Shift + End` works a treat.

Edit: Works in Notepad++ too.

Comment: Exactlywhat I was looking for! Also found out that you can reorder Notepad++ files with `Ctrl + Shift + Page Up/Down`.